# Cannot attach the file ‘{0}' as database '{1}'. Code first. Local SQL EXPRESS Instance. VS 2010 SP1. Windows XP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've been using Code First approach. I created a sql express local database "Database.mdf" in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 using MVC 4 template. When I try to run my project at my PC, I get an error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database master. Cannot attach
>   the file "...Database.mdf" as database file "Database".

What I've tried:

- deletion my database using SQL SERVER Object explorer(no results, the same error)
- change connection string (no result, the same error)
- googled in the Internet. However, I've met examples where people use real SQL servers, not the local DB.

My connection string is:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; InitialCatalog=Database; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf; IntegratedSecurity=true;"
```

Please, pay attention that I use local database, not the real SQL SERVER and my Visual Studio is 2010.

I try to run this code:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

How to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to run VS as Admin ?

Comment: Try this solution - may be this is your case  - http://codeverge.com/asp.net.sql-datasource/create-database-permission-denied-in-d/593607

Comment: Show us some more code. What query are you firing after the connection string?

Comment: @Dr. .Net , I've added the code.

Comment: You're not using localdb.  That connection string is to your local SqlExpress instance, not your LocalDb instance.  SqlExpress and LocalDb are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a LocalDb connection string.  A LocalDb connection string looks like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: @StepUp - you also need the Initial Catalog statement, which I didn't include.  Regardless, you're not using localdb unless you use the (localdb)\v11.0 datasource, otherwise you're just using sql express as standard sql server.

Comment: If I write connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True", I get an error "Invalid key value: AttachDBFilename". However, ".\sqlexpress" works perfectly.

Comment: @StepUp - as I said, you're not using localdb when you do that.  If that's fine, and you don't care that you need to have SQL Server Express installed where it's going to be used, then ok.  The whole point of localdb is so that you don't need an instance of Sql Express.

Comment: I have not installed SQL Server Express. SQL Server express is internal part of VS 2010. If I write your connstring: connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;...", then I catch an exception. If I write "connstring=/.sqlexpress" , it works okay. However, WebSecurity cannot create tables in my internal DB of my application. It throws exception - Cannot attach the file ‘{0}' as database '{1}'

Comment: Localdb does not come with VS 2010.  See the v11?  That indicates SQL Server v11 which is SQL Server 2012.  In fact, VS2010 doesn't support LocalDb out of the box, there is a walkthrough here though. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/11/28/using-localdb-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: I've seen this article and I tried conn string "localdb/v11.0", but it does not work and never databases are shown. If I write ".\sqlexpress", it is possible to see local databases.

Comment: @StepUp - I give up, you seem completely unable to understand English.

Comment: I am not sure that I use correct name for local database. I just clicked by right button of mouse at the project - Add->Add Element->Data->Database SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new empty Database (Graphical) in your SQL Express.
2. Change your connection string "InitialCatalog" to something else like : InitialCatalog=Database1;.
3. Run your project and use one query.