# Commands are not working of sqllocalDB in Package Manager Console of VS 2010 SP1

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, package-managers

I'm encountering the exact issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440143/cannot-attach-the-file-0-as-database-1-code-first-localdb-vs-2010-sp1)(EF: Cannot attach the file ‘{0}' as database '{1}').
My question is how to run these commands in  Package Manager Console of Visual Studio 2010 SP1:

- sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0
- sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0
- update-Database

All these commands perfectly run in  Package Manager Console of VS 2012, but when I try to run these commands in VS 2010 SP1, then VS 2010 SP1 cannot recognize them.

**What are alternative commands in  Package Manager Console of VS 2010 SP1?**

Comment: localdb comes as part of VS2012 so it is probably in in the PMC path. Try putting the full path to sqllocaldb.exe, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe`

Comment: @Rhumborl, like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe stop v11.0?

Comment: sorry wasn't clear, yes like `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" stop v11.0`. Add quotes around the path because it has spaces in it